Paranormal investigators in San Francisco, a school for girls where it turns out they're teaching witchcraft
I saw part of this show (maybe it was a movie, but I think it was an episode of a series) on late night TV sometime in the early/mid 1990s. Based on where I would have to have been to see it, it was either the winter of 1993/94 or the winter of 1996/97 (those were the only times in that period when I lived somewhere with a working TV, and the places were similar enough that I'm not sure which it was). Nothing in it (clothes, cars, etc) seemed outdated, so it must have been made around that time.
It was about a group of paranormal investigators in San Francisco. I remember the setting clearly, because I'm originally from there but was no longer living there by then, so it always stood out for me. There was at least one woman and at least two men. They were investigating a school for girls, and it turned out in the end that the girls were being taught witchcraft. The final scene involved a satanic ritual/lots of chanting/human sacrifice kind of setup (the human sacrifice was stopped by the investigators, if I remember correctly). 
Details I remember: the female investigator goes to the school and meets with the headmistress. The headmistress says something like, "We're teaching these girls to be strong women." Meanwhile, one of the girls sneaks up on the investigator and steals her scarf. The scarf later turns up as something they're using to cast a spell on her.
One of the girls is named Rachel. I think she's the one who steals the scarf.
There's another girl named Patty, and she seems to be betraying the group. As I recall, she'd talked to the investigators, or said something to someone that got them interested. Patty is in the hospital, and the school sends her a doll. The nurse puts it on the dresser in her room. As soon as the nurse leaves, the doll turns her head from side to side, saying in a creepy voice, "Patty, Patty, in your little bed, Patty, Patty, soon you will be dead."

Is this movie in color or black and white?

You're after the Canadian horror series Poltergeist: The Legacy that ran for 4 seasons in 1996-1999.

"The Legacy" is a secret society that began many centuries ago to accumulate knowledge and artifacts to help fight against the evil in the world. This particular Legacy team is set in San Francisco in a castle-like house on Angel Island. Dr. Derek Rayne heads up the team comprised of psychiatrist, Rachel Corrigan; priest, Philip C.; ex-Navy SEAL, Nick Boyle; and researcher/psychic Alex Moreau.

The episode you're looking for is Revelations (Season 1, episode 17).

A small girl has a horrifying experience at a private school and accuses one of the teachers of being a monster. As Rachel used to go to the school the headmistress calls her up to ask her for help. She hopes that Rachel will be able to find out what really happened before the school is ruined by the scandal. As she investigates Rachel realises that she has no memories of being at the school at all! She knows she went there but can remember nothing and that begins to really worry her.

Every single detail you remembered is there (the scarf, Patty's doll singing the creepy song etc.) Here's the team (in season 3):

